# Python: find the exponent of two numbers using only incrementation/addition by 1(+=1), can not use multiplication or division operators.

Tags: python, function, while-loop, increment, square

I am trying to find the exponent of two numbers (**n**,**m**) using the only arithmetic operation of incrementation "+=1" by 1. I can not use any other addition/multiplication or division operators.  The program can be a function or a loop such that the user enters **n**, and them **m** and the program calculates **n** raised to the power of **m**.

There is one question closely related to mine already posted **BUT** it is looking for **one**, **odd** numbered square AND the addition operator is allowed. The related question does not help me raise the value of **n** by the value of **m**. Here is the code I have so far, it will multiply but not square based on user inputs. Thanks in advance!

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())

i=0
acc=0
while i < m:
    acc+=n
    i+=1
print(acc)
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this, we need to understand first: What is multiplication?

`a x b` is equivalent to `a + a + a +...` b times. Then, what is exponent? `a^b` is equivalent to `a x a x a x..` b times. So, you would need two while loops and two counters.

```
n = int(input("n value: "))
m = int(input("m value: "))

def add(a, b):
    num = a
    for i in range(b):
        num += 1
    return num

def multiply(a, b):
    num = 0
    for i in range(b):
        num = add(num, a)
    return num

def exponent(a, b):
    num = 1
    for i in range(b):
        num = multiply(num, a)
    return num

print(exponent(n, m))
```

Comment: you should change loop count logic as op cannot use "-=1", but this is trivial modification to make it use +=1 instead

Comment: `num += a` needs unrolling too.

Comment: Thanks Moon Cheesez, the code you provided is easy for me to follow since it is the same type and level of code I am currently writing. With Paul's and @Lejot's comment included your code is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you to all!

Answer (score 2):

Functional programming works nicely here. Addition is repeated incrementing. Multiplication is repeated addition. Power is repeated multiplication.

By defining a function (`repeat`) that repeatedly applies a function to an argument a given number of times, one can build up the `power` function.

Here's the code.

```
def repeat(f, n, x):
    a = 0
    while a != n:
        x = f(x)
        a = a + 1
    return x

inc = lambda a: a+1
add = lambda a: lambda b: repeat(inc, a, b)
mult = lambda a: lambda b: repeat(add(a), b, 0)
power = lambda a: lambda b: repeat(mult(a), b, 1)

print power(3)(7)
```

The only built-in arithmetic performed is incrementing by 1 and an equality comparison in the `while` loop in the `repeat` function.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your code it works great! But I am not sure if I can use the Lambda function. I am new to python so it is something I will keep and use for future reference.

Comment: @TheodoreHarrison You should be allowed to use the `lambda` function as it is just a shorthand for defining a function. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Comment: MoonCheesez, yes you are correct. After researching it a bit, Lambda is a much simpler, shorter way to define a function. Thank you for the link and @PaulHankin for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

With only `+= 1` as arithmetical operation, your solution could look like this:

```
def mul(n, m): 
    result = 0 
    mi = 0 
    while mi < m:
        ni = 0 
        while ni < n:
            result += 1
            ni += 1
        mi += 1
    return result

def pow(n, e): 
    result = 1 
    ei = 0 
    while ei < e:
        result = mul(result, n)
    ei += 1
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    e = int(input())
    print(pow(n, e))
```